# Why is the first-child considered a pseudo selector but a pseudo element like the first-line?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I mean they both are dynamic and actualy exists in DOM. I think generally I know difference between pseudo elements and selectors but this one is a little bit subtle that makes me confused.

Comment: First child is an element, first-line is not

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as a "pseudo selector".

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements):

> Pseudo-elements create abstractions about the document tree beyond those specified by the document language.

and

> Pseudo-classes classify elements on characteristics other than their name, attributes or content; in principle characteristics that cannot be deduced from the document tree.

---

`:first-child` is a pseudo-class because it selects an element.

```
<div>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
</div>
```

`<span>a</span>` is the first child.

`:first-line` is a pseudo-element because it selects something that is no a real element.

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
```

The characters that are part of the `:first-line` are determined by where the text node happens to word-wrap, not by the start and end tag for an element.